# How to implement timer callback on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Consider implementing poker on Google App Engine. Suppose a player is allowed only 10 seconds to check/fold/raise.

That is, if 10 seconds pass with no response from the player then some timer should fire which executes code that writes to DataStore declaring that the player folded. What is the idiomatic way to implement this on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAE has a feature called "Tasks". Sadly, they have no guaranteed resolution, so a task scheduled for now+10 seconds can execute in 10 seconds or *any later* time.

Solution: Write the current time-stamp along with the information about the current player into the database. If any of the players request updated information about the current game, you can check this time-stamp, compare it with the current one, and therefore determine if these 10 seconds have passed and update the database accordingly.

You can combine this solution with tasks to ensure, that even if nobody "watches" that game, its still updated sometime.

Comment: I quite like that, you won't use up datastore resources unless somebody comes and checks the results of the game. The reason I like the backend version is it's all "in memory" with the datastore only used as periodic backup.

Comment: But backends wont scale.. It will work for 10 concurrent games, 100, and maybe 1000. It definitely wont work for +10.000. Then you'll have to manually distribute that load across several backends (the maximum amount of concurrent backend-instances is limited!) and end-up reimplementing exactly what the appengine was designed to handle for you...

Comment: Backends are there for a purpose. If you can accurately calculate the resource usage you can ensure that scaling is not an issue as you'll never need to use more resources then one backend can provide. And if you do, then you can start another. And you can allow the frontend instances to scale up and down as required. Should it get to the point where more then one backend is required then that is just another problem to solve. And don't forget 1000 concurrent games can run 500 on one backend and 500 on another, as long as you can tie a particular game to a particular server.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done on a backend, as that's the only code that can persist outside of a request handler.

- Player is dealt.   Timer starts on backend.  Timer expires.  Player
  status updated.

> Backends are special App Engine instances that have no request deadlines, higher memory and CPU limits, and persistent state across requests. They are started automatically by App Engine and can run continously for long periods. Each backend instance has a unique URL to use for requests, and you can load-balance requests across multiple instances.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

Comment: So you're positive there is no way to do this stateless?

Comment: oh, I'm sure there would be a way but why bother when that's what backends are for. You could, for example, have a task that checks the datastore for expired rounds every second then calls itself to check again but of course that'll use up lots of resources just checking over and over again. Perhaps somebody else will have a stateless version that wont' suffer from those problems. Memcache would not be reliable for this.

Comment: The documentation you linked to says that App Engine may shutdown a backend or that something unexpected could happen. How can shutdowns be handled? How can the use of backends be done in a way that is fault tolerant?

Comment: that's up to you to build in. You usually get some warning before that happens so you can trigger your "save everything to the datastore" routines, or you persist to the datastore every so often. The fact is that 100% uptime is not available on anything anywhere so you have to take that into account when building your app on GAE or any other platform at all.

Comment: you could, I suppose, use tasks - start one in 10 seconds time that'll close the hand if no update by then, but I doubt that tasks will run with the accuracy (sub second) that's needed here.

Answer (score 1):

No need to act synchronously - i.e. do some action exactly 10 seconds after last user action.

Just record the time of last user action and act accordingly next time the user action happens: if <10s let user do next move, if >10s notify user he folded.

To keep things more responsive, e.g. to show user how much time he hes before folding, you should also track this on client.